# RPM spec for glibc

Tags: rpm, glibc, specifications

I am looking for RPM `.spec` for `glibc` (for `glibc-2.18` or newer), on Fedora distribution. Where can I find it? Is the only solution to create it by my own?

Comment: The spec-file would be in the source-rpm, which you can find on the web, e.g., [rpmfind.net](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=glibc)

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. As you said - I took it from src.rpm and it worked. I found what I was looking for at rpm.pbone.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the best solution for RPM .specs (which are not available by default in the software source package) is taking it from appropriate source RPM.